# Understanding the In-band Emission limit in TS 38101-1 Table 6.4.2.3-1?

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm, lte, communication-standard

I am sharing the IBE table 6.4.2.3-1 on TS 38101-1
[image]

For **General emission requirement**, there are three parts.The third part is (-57 dBm+10*log10(scs/15kHz))-P_RB. Where, P_RB is the average transmitted power normalized by the Allocated RB's in dBm. My Question is :

1. What is the significance of this third term as this only deals with transmitted output power.

I have second question regarding the summing of all three parameter (General, IQ image, Carrier Leakage). I would like to explain using a hypothetical to elaborate my understanding.

Suppose, I have a **9RB's in a channel BW**, in which the **first two is allocated** and **last 7 is unallocated**. **Carrier leakage related to 5th RB**, **IQ image is 8th and 9th RB**. My output power is 20 dBm.NRB=9, LCRB=2. P_RB=17 dBm (average of two allocated RBs. Ref: Note 10).

```
General Requirement: [d d a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7];  %d: Allocated RB location not included in limit calculation. 
%a:- represent some value in dB we get after general limit calculation (Table)

IQ image: [d d 0 0 0 0 0 28 28];  [-28 dB : From Table]

Carrier leakage:  [d d 0 0 28 0 0 0 0];  [-28 dBc: From Table]
```

**According to Note 1: I need to power sum all this three.**

```
General+IQ+Carrier Leakage=[d d a1 a2 (a3+28) a4 a5 (a6+28) (a7+28) ]
```

**My question 2:**

I just added the IQ limit and Carrier leakage limit in absolute dB with General results in allocated RB position. But note 1 says regarding the "Power sum". Do I need to convert all of them into watt and then sum all of them? or I can do this simply in dB scale like I did?  I am a bit confused regarding the summing. Thank you.